# How to add zend form element at specific position, after once form object has already created?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have created one user_form class that extends zend form, it has 4 elements username, password, hash for csrf and at last submit button.

Creating object of user_form renders all those four element.

After validating login in controller action i checks fail attempts, and after some fix number of fail attempts I want to add zend captch before submit button.

I added captcha element and it was appended at after submit button.

How can I add zend element at specific position? Or How can i add it before submit button?

Also let me know that the way am I doing is proper?
Waiting for your reply.
Thank you...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give your elements order numbers from the very begining. Add an order number to the captcha element, when you add it.

```
$element->setOrder(10);
```

or

```
$form->addElement('text', 'username', array('order' => 10));
```

See also the [Zend_Form manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html).

Comment: Wasn't aware of this. Removed my answer.

Comment: link is dead :( but I'm using ZF2 now

Answer (score 6):

You can either use `setOrder()`as markus said, or when you render your form in your viewscript, you can render each field separately:

```
// .phtml
<form id="form" action="<?= $this->escape($this->form->getAction()); ?>" method="<?= $this->escape($this->form->getMethod()); ?>">
<table>
  <?= $this->form->username ?>
  <?= $this->form->password ?>
  <?= $this->form->hash ?>
  <?= $this->form->captcha ?>
  <?= $this->form->submit ?>
</table>
</form>
```